# Подключение @media screen в css

Tags: css, media-queries

Работает только для 1 стиля:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {.footer {width:750px;margin:auto;}}
```

Если добавить 2 стиль:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .footer {
        width:750px;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .ftmenu{
        width:300px;
    }
}
```

То правило для `ftmenu` не действует.
Если для каждого стиля отдельно писать `@media screen and (max-width: 800px)` то работает нормально, в чем проблема?

Comment: Пример на jsfiddle можно?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте дать вес вашему правилу или напишите его в самом низу `css` файла:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .footer {
        width:750px;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .ftmenu{
        width:300px !important;
    }
}
```

Поскольку в на строке `http://www.softgoal.ru/templates/softgoal/css/style.css:626` у вас прописана ширина 500 пикс для данного блока, то есть ниже того места, где вы пишите `media-queries`, то это правило просто переопределяет вышеописанное правило.

Не забывайте пользоваться консолью для разработчика, там сразу все видно. Вот апрув – http://joxi.ru/GrqebPefyGDvrz

Тот случай, когда у вас все правило работало если вы писали в отдельном `media-queries` скорее всего вы писали ниже строки `style.css:626`.

### UPD

Вот [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137588/) про вес для `CSS` правил.